# Apache2 Virtualhost takes me to root directory

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, virtual-host

I have a virtual host created under `/etc/apache2/sites-available` called **attrave.com.conf**

Here is the code for that virtual host file (only relevant code attached):

```
ServerName attrave.com
ServerAdmin bonyuuuc@gmail.com
ServerAlias www.attrave.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/attrave.com

<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/attrave.com>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>
```

I would like to be able to access the site `www.attrave.com` also by just `attrave.com`.

Currently when I browse to `attrave.com` it takes me to the `/var/www/` directory when it should really take me to the actual **attrave.com** folder. When I include `www.` everything works but this is frustrating.

**EDIT:** Here is my updated virtual host file: **(THIS STILL DOES NOT WORK)**

```
# Ensure that Apache listens on port 80
Listen 80

# Listen for virtual host requests on all IP addresses
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
# The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
# the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
# redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
# specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
# match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
# value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
# However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.

ServerName www.attrave.com
ServerAdmin bouuuuc@gmail.com
ServerAlias www.attrave.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/attrave.com

<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/attrave.com>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I have tried using all your suggessions and I'm still not able to get the site working under **"attrave.com"**. It works under **"www.attrave.com"**.

I am attaching text of relevant content, that hopefully allow you guys to have more insight on this issue.

- Attrave.com.conf (virtual host file)

  ```
  DocumentRoot /var/www/attrave.com
  ServerName attrave.com
  ServerAlias attrave.com www.attrave.com
  ServerAdmin bouuuuic@gmail.com


  <Directory /var/www/attrave.com>
          Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
          AllowOverride All
          Order allow,deny
          allow from all
  </Directory>
  ```
- /etc/hosts file

  ```
  # Your system has configured 'manage_etc_hosts' as True.
  # As a result, if you wish for changes to this file to persist
  # then you will need to either
  # a.) make changes to the master file in /etc/cloud/templates/hosts.tmpl
  # b.) change or remove the value of 'manage_etc_hosts' in
  #     /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg or cloud-config from user-data

  127.0.0.1 localhost
  ```
- Apache2.conf file

  ```
   <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
   </Directory>

  <Directory /usr/share>
   AllowOverride None
   Require all granted
  </Directory>

  <Directory /var/www/>
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride None
   Require all granted
   </Directory>

   #<Directory /srv/>
   #  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   #   AllowOverride None
   #   Require all granted
  #</Directory>
  ```

Answer (score -1):

did u tried:

```
# Ensure that Apache listens on port 80
Listen 80

# Listen for virtual host requests on all IP addresses
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/attrave.com
    Servername attrave.com
    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I've checked the cname. www is added to it. Also my problem is not with www.attrave.com My problem is with when i browse to **attrave.com** it takes me to the /var/www root directory. I hope i can get this fixed!

Comment: what does `dig attrave.com` look like?

Comment: `; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.2-Ubuntu <<>> attrave.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 12031
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;attrave.com.   IN A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
attrave.com.  1799 IN A 45.55.165.145

;; Query time: 125 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Thu Apr 23 10:15:38 EDT 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 56`

Comment: check edited answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, That didn't work it is still giving me the same root directory.

Comment: now i'm getting a new error when I try to reload apache2. `AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using attrave.com. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80`

Comment: Use the host (A) in servername attrave.com directive

Comment: @FranciscoTapia When i tried to update the virtual host file to your changes above: that's when i started running into the "address already in use and other similar errors". (just want to let you know I have another domain using virtual host in this same server that works completely fine using my original virtualhost config, so I am clueless why this is happening.

Comment: @mat srry I can't help anymore, coni haven't enought reputation points to deserve it, les w8 for someone more qualiticated guy or with more badges answer that, srry mate